# A nightmare for kids

Tags: riddle

> A nightmare for kids,
>
> You can make them stop just by saying my name.
>
> No matter your size, I will hug you.
>
> Discreet, people don't pay attention to me,
>
> But without me, you can say bye to your pride.
>
> You can even say bye to your life.

**Who am I?**

My first riddle, invented this morning. Pretty proud of this one.
If you have some advice, it's welcome. (I'm not english)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling :).

Comment: Is it 'Discrete' or 'Discreet'? (I think it's the second one, but I'm not sure).

Comment: You're right, Discreet. Pardon my french. Edited

Comment: Is synonyms of the word involved or one word fits all the lines?

Comment: One word can fit all the lines, with the good explanation ^^ ( I'll put some hints later, if too hard)

Comment: Teacher?.......

Comment: 'Bye' to my pride? Hardly :-)

Comment: @Strawberry of course, if you don't have one, more difficult to loose it :p

Comment: @Guildias lol :-)

Comment: Wild guess: "Hillary C. as their teacher and/or nanny?".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Is it

> belt

A nightmare for kids,
You can make them stop just by saying my name.

> In some countries spanking a child with a belt is a form of punishment.

No matter your size, I will hug you.

> A belt "hugs" any person wearing it.

Discreet, people don't pay attention to me,
But without me, you can say bye to your pride.

> Your pants may drop, leading to huge embarrassment.

You can even say bye to your life.

> You may die if you don't use a *seat* belt.

Comment: I think this is 'fitting' answer

Comment: Can you please add an explanation for the rest of the lines?

Comment: Good work ! If you can explain all the lines, it will be great ;)

Comment: I don't see how I would say bye to my life without a belt...

Comment: @smriti thanks for the edit, it was hard to format it appropriately on my phone...

Answer (score 8):

Answer:

> Sleep

A nightmare for kids,

> Kids don't want to go to sleep (at least mine doesn't)

You can make them stop just by saying my name.

> Kids get all nervous when they hear about sleep

No matter your size, I will hug you.

> Everyone needs to sleep.

Discret, people don't pay attention to me,

> you are not paying attention to anything when you sleep.

But without me, you can say bye to your pride.

> Sleep deprivation is bad...really really bad.

You can even say bye to your life.

> You can die from sleep deprivation

Bonus: "My first riddle, invented this morning."

> you were still sleepy and you didn't want to get up.

Comment: It can fit. Really good one, but still not the answer I'm looking for. Upvote for the bonus ;) (and good luck with your kids)

Comment: nice bonus hahaha

Comment: you are not paying attention to sleep when you are in sleep.haha

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it is :

> Silence

A nightmare for kids,

> Sure they hate it

You can make them stop just by saying my name.

> If you say it, they become quiet

No matter your size, I will hug you.

> Silence can be overwhelming

Discreet, people don't pay attention to me,

> Who pay attention to quiet people ?

But without me, you can say bye to your pride.

> If you speak to much, you can say stupid things

You can even say bye to your life.

> Speaking too much can get you killed... sometimes...

Answer (score 3):

You are

> Doctor

A nightmare for kids,

> It is.

You can make them stop just by saying my name.

> Mom,i won't through glass this time,please don't call doctor.

No matter your size, I will hug you.

> how much fit you are,some diseases always with you(i have color blindness) ,definitely you should meet doctor(sorry,no hug)

Discrete, people don't pay attention to me,

> Everyone talking about Donald Trump.Don't ignore doctor,they are very important to humanity

But without me, you can say bye to your pride.

> If you get no right prescription medicines provided by doctor,then....

You can even say bye to your life.

> Without them ,this is true

Comment: Really creative. I'm almost sad that this isn't the good answer. x) +1 for the Trump

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Father

A nightmare for kids,

> Generally, kids are scared of their father, atleast I was.

You can make them stop just by saying my name.

> My mom used to scare me by saying that she will tell father about the mischevous things I used to do.

No matter your size, I will hug you.

> Father hugs everyone, be it his kids or their mom :)

Discreet, people don't pay attention to me,

> Not sure about this one, but certainly kids don't listen to their fathers

But without me, you can say bye to your pride.

> A father is someone u look up to in your life. One should be proud of his/her father

You can even say bye to your life.

> Certainly you were not even born without him. :)

Comment: This isn't your father. I like the start, but quickly it begin to be far-fetched ^^

Comment: I know it was too specific... but believe it was the very first thing that came to my mind after reading your riddle :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> Name

A nightmare for kids,

> Kids don't like their names

You can make them stop just by saying my name.

> If you want to stop smb. call him by name

No matter your size, I will hug you.

> There is a name for everything, no matter what size it is

Discret, people don't pay attention to me,

> Just a name, regular thing

But without me, you can say bye to your pride.

> Nameless Author, we know what you've done, but we don't know who you are

You can even say bye to your life.

> It's hard to live without name

Comment: Not bad ! But the answer has already been found, and it's not this.

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> Needles? Like in vaccinations?

A nightmare for kids
You can make them stop just by saying my name.

> Some kids are incredibly scared of getting a vaccination shot

No matter your size, I will hug you.

> Needles go into everyone and, uh, "hug" them, if you want to call it that. You could maybe use this as a euphemism to make it easier on the kid?

Discreet, people don't pay attention to me,

> Needles are very thin and small, and with infants some doctors try to to do it in a way that the kid won't notice.

But without me, you can say bye to your pride.

> Well, considering what kind of sicknesses you can get if you refuse vaccination, some have long-lasting effects which will make life very hard on you.

You can even say bye to your life.

> You could die - in the long run - by refusing vaccinations

Comment: This isn't. The "hug" explanation is really weird ^^

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> Cold/Cool

A nightmare for kids,

> When kids get cold, it is really a nightmare, especially to really small one's

You can make them stop just by saying my name.

> Don't stand under the shower too much, you will get cold

No matter your size, I will hug you.

> You will get cold whether you are big or small.

Discreet, people don't pay attention to me,

> I know it is bit of a stretch. But I think discreet people pretend to be cool, and hide their feelings.

But without me, you can say bye to your pride.

> If you always lose your cool, you won't be in others good book. Not good for your pride.

You can even say bye to your life.

> Same, if you don't control your temper, your life can get bad without you knowing it.

Comment: Nice try, but like you said, a little stretch on some explanation. This isn't. ^^

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

> Water

Because:

A nightmare for kids,

> learning to swim is scary at first

You can make them stop just by saying my name.

> when they are making noise and the teacher is coming, you shout "water!"

No matter your size, I will hug you.

> water can surround you completely

Discret, people don't pay attention to me,

> is so normal

You can even say bye to your life.

> is essential!

Comment: What about "But without me, you can say bye to your pride." ?

Comment: im still on it ^^'

Comment: He bye already that line.

Comment: Sorry mate, but it's not water. Didn't know the teacher shout "water", tho. I least not in my country ^^ And still curious about the pride :p

Comment: not the teacher, other classmates. I know it in other situations also like the police nearby or so. i cant match the pride sentence. and sorry to hear is not the answer  v.v